# Android - Array of DragControllers

Tags: android, arrays, adapter

How to set an array of controllers to use with different gridViews, so I can use them somewhat like this?

```
private DragController mDragController[]; 
..
 mDragController[1] = new DragController (ManageRooms.this);
 dynGrid.setAdapter (new ImageCellAdapter (ManageRooms.this, mDragController[1]));
```

Now it just crashes the app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was missing this line:

```
private DragController[] mDragController = new DragController[numberOfControllers];
```